# Generic way to map old spring classes to new spring packages

Tags: spring

We are migrating from Spring 2.6 and the huge package (org.springframework.spring) has been divided into multiple sub-packages. Is there an easy way to find out which class has been moved to which package. Search for the package name in maven or over the internet didn't help much. It just points to old packages or the latest spring java doc which doesn't say the spring subproject. Is there an easy way to get this information.

Comment: `We are migrating from Spring 2.6 ` its like application rewrite. Plan and migrate slowly.

Comment: I do not think there is a way for such compatible problems.

Comment: ok than looks like I have lot of browsing to do. Thanks for your inputs though.